# Unable to start program 'F:\C++ Projects\Advanced 2D Game Development\Engine\msvc8\Advanced2D.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

So I am using the book "Advanced 2D Game Development" by Jonathan S. Harbour, and I've upgraded the MSVC 2008 project to MSVC 2010 Express.
I have 2 projects within the solution; "Advanced2D" and "TestEngine". Advanced2D contains the entry point, the class definitions for the game engine.
By upgrading from MSVC 2008 up to MSVC 2010 it had everything set to create as a .lib file. TestEngine contains 4 functions currently, that Advanced2D calls on. These are game_preload(), game_init(), game_update(), and game_end().
It says the "engine" itself is the library, while the TestEngine calls upon it. The book specifically says to not worry about a "bin" folder just yet, "because we are not yet working on an executable program, just a library project." Yet the library project contains the entry point; "winmain.cpp".

The project builds correctly, everything is linked correctly I'm sure of it.

However, when I try to debug the program I get this error.

> Unable to start program 'F:\C++ Projects\Advanced 2D Game
>   Development\Engine\msvc8\Advanced2D.lib'.
>
> The specified file is an unrecognized or unsupported binary format.

I have just updated the project to MSVC 2015, and the issue persists.

The error in MSVC 2015 is:

> F:\C++ Projects\Advanced 2D Game Development\Engine\msvc8\Advanced2D.lib is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: The error message should be obvious as to the problem.   Why are you starting a `.lib` library file and not an executable (`.exe`)?

Comment: When I add a secondary project to the solution that builds to an .exe, I still get the error.

Comment: Have you set your executable as active?

Comment: Look at the project configuration properties and see the "Debugging" option.  What do you see as the "Command" that is to be run?  Also, it is the **active** or "Startup" project that is debugged.  Is the executable the startup project?

Comment: The second project should be the active project I think. The first project contains the windows code, while the second project contains the game logic. In this case, it just displays a MessageBox.

Comment: The command dialog entry says:
$(TargetPath)

Comment: Which project contains the executable?  Also, the active project is the one that is "Bolded" when viewing in the Solution Explorer.  It is the bolded project that is being "run", and I would suspect that what is being run is the project that builds the library, which is not the correct active project.

Comment: I have 2 projects within the solution; "Advanced2D" and "TestEngine". Advanced2D contains the entry point, the class definitions for the game engine. By upgrading from MSVC 2008 up to MSVC 2010 it had everything set to create as a .lib file.

TestEngine contains 4 functions currently, that Advanced2D calls on. These are game_preload(), game_init(), game_update(), and game_end().

Do I need to set Advanced2D to build to .exe? It causes different errors.
Thank you for the information about Active project. Learn something new every day.

Comment: Advanced2D can't **call on** anything in TestEngine. It's a **library**. It contains functions that are **called** by your application, in this case TestEngine. You **cannot** run a library or DLL; they're designed to be loaded by an executable (.exe) and the executable uses the library, not the other way around. You may need to go over your book's lessons again to figure out what you missed.

Comment: It says the "engine" itself is the library, while the TestEngine calls upon it. The book specifically says to not worry about a "bin" folder just yet, "because we are not yet working on an executable program, just a library project."

Yet the library project contains the entry point; "winmain.cpp". Should I move my windows code to the other project?

Comment: I got it working. I had to link the library file to the TestEngine project, and I have completely missed the section after the source code that explained how to set up the project.

You'd think setting up the project would come before the source code... but whatever. Thank you for your help.